# Regex Expression to check lower case or uppercase in and string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var fs = require('fs');
var a =fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString();
var res = a.split(",");
for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++)
{
    res[i] = parseInt(res[i], 10);
}

function t(res){
    
 try { 
    if(res.length <8)  throw "a weak Password";
    if(res.length==8) throw "an average Password";
   if(res.length>8) throw "a strong Password";
  }
   catch(err) {
  return(err);
  }
  
}

function passwordEncryption(res){
   var tem= t(res);
  
    for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
       res[i]=(String.fromCharCode(res[i]));
    }
    var string =res.join("")
    console.log(`${string} is ${tem}`)
   
    
}
passwordEncryption(res)
```

can some add regex contrains in this

Problem Description:

Read ‘n’ number of inputs from file ‘input.txt’.

Each line of input contains 8 comma-seperated ASCII values corresponding to the password.(Example: 80,97,115,115,49,50,49,52)

Decode the ASCII values to characters.(Example:  Pass1214)

Password must contain atleast 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 number. (Check the constraint using regex)

If ASCII values are less than 8, then throw the error manually with message ‘Weak Password’.

Catch the error and print the same.

If ASCII values are equal to 8, then decode it to characters with the message ‘Average Password’

If ASCII values greater than 8, then decode it to characters with the message ‘Strong Password’.

If ASCII values are not valid, then print the message ‘Invalid Password’. (Example: Any special characters)

Create function named as ‘passwordEncryption’.

Inside the function generate the encrypted password for given ASCII values.

Input and Output Format:

Refer to sample input and output.

Input is a set of ASCII values for a password.

Output is encrypted passwords along with its messages.

Input 1:

80,97,115,115,49,50,49,52

Output 1:

‘Pass1214’ is an average password

Input 2:

80,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,49,50,49,52

Output 2:

‘Password1214’ is a strong password

Input 3:

80,97,115,115,119,111,114

Output 3:

Weak password

Input 4:

80,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,49,50,42
Output 4:

‘Password12*’ is an invalid password

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The regexp `/[a-z]/` will match a lowercase letter, `/[A-Z]/` will match an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to detect, using regex, if a password contains uppercase, lowercase, and length >= 8, you can use three look-aheads:

- [`(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*`](https://regex101.com/r/ah1sRH/1)

[image]